# How to add static header image in custom listview?

Tags: android, listview

I will put a picture on top of a custom list view for the header image, but the image is repeated, how can I make it can't click and non-repeatable?
this is my xml code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/abs__background_holo_light" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/detailImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/pantaigoacina" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/detailImage"
        android:background="@color/abs__background_holo_light" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/abs__background_holo_light"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/list_image"
                android:layout_width="15dip"
                android:layout_height="15dip" 
                android:src="@drawable/arrow"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NamaLokasi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:text="Pantai Sipelot"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detailLokasi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/NamaLokasi"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:text="Deskripsi Konten, Lokasi Berada di Desa Wilayah Malang"
            android:textColor="#343434"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my adapter :

```
String[] from = { "pantai", "detail" };
int[] to = { R.id.NamaLokasi, R.id.detailLokasi };

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity()
        .getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.fragment_detail, from,
        to);

setListAdapter(adapter);

return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

[image: this is the header when repeated]

Comment: ListView has `addheaderView(view)`. You can add a view as a header to listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the image form the xml.

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(getActivity());
// set image to imageview
ListView list = getListView();
list.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

The docs

```
public void addHeaderView (View v)

Added in API level 1
Add a fixed view to appear at the top of the list. If addHeaderView is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.

Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter). Starting with KITKAT, this method may be called at any time. If the ListView's adapter does not extend HeaderViewListAdapter, it will be wrapped with a supporting instance of WrapperListAdapter.

Parameters
v   The view to add.
```

Edit:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceStat)
    {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
               list = getListView();
       ImageView imageHeaderView = new ImageView(getActivity());
       imageHeaderView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pantaigoacina));

       list.addHeaderView(imageHeaderView);

       List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

       for (int i = 0; i < DaerahWisata.pantai.length; i++) {
               HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
               hm.put("pantai", DaerahWisata.pantai[i]);
               hm.put("detail", "Lokasi : \r\n" + DaerahWisata.detailp[i]);
               aList.add(hm);
       }

       String[] from = { "pantai", "detail" };
       int[] to = { R.id.NamaLokasi, R.id.detailLokasi };

       SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity()
                       .getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.fragment_detail, from,
                       to);           
       setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Edit, if want to set imageview from other xml layout :

```
list = getListView();
    Context context = getListView().getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_header, null);
    list.addHeaderView(view);
```

Comment: I've tried your code, there is error message like this:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created

this is my activity fragment :
[Source Code FragmentDetail.java](http://pastebin.com/4LnJyHcV).

Comment: @NafianWildana move the code to `onActivityCreated` and it will work

Comment: @NafianWildana if you still find difficulty leave a comment

Comment: @NafianWildana check the update. Now it will work as expected

Comment: sorry, my last question, how to set size of imageview height programatically? i have search tutorial about this, and this is my code : imageHeaderView.getLayoutParams().width = //value of screen height
but, allways nullpointerexception, any other ways to set this image size? thanks before

Comment: @NafianWildana you can set the height ans width progrmatically. Or have imageview in a separate xml with height and width inflate the view and then add it as a header

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:-

```
ImageView imageHeaderView = new ImageView(this);//use getActivity() on fragment
imageHeaderView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.deckblatt));

myList.addHeaderView(imageHeaderView);
```

Comment: my class is extends SherlockListFragment , and i dont declare listtView, how to add this list?
i'm new in android apps development.

Comment: @NafianWildana i dont declare listtView why ?

Comment: @NafianWildana try my post